# ASP.NET MVC ajax post function sending null values

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My apologies if there is an answer already out there for this, I could not find one.

I have an ajax function that posting data to a controller, but some of the data being sent have null values. Here is my setup:

I have 3 parameters being sent to the controller: data, rptnew and recid.
The data parameter is a string containing db column names and data.
rptnew and recid only contain one value.

```
var data = "{'DATEWORKING':'" + $('#HEADER-DATEWORKING').val() +
        "','TRAYS':'" + $('#TRAYS').val() +
        "','M26850':'" + $('#INCOMINGMAIL5').val() +
        "','M26860':'" + $('#INCOMINGMAIL6').val() +
        "','X26930':'" + $('#INCOMINGMAIL9').val() +
        "','T26920':'" + $('#INCOMINGMAIL8').val() +
        "','C2501':'" + $('#INCOMINGMAIL1').val()+ "'}";
rptnew = '0';
recid = '2347';
```

function post:

```
function postdata(data, section, recid, rptnew) {
$.ajax
    ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'UpdateDB_IR’,
        async: false,
        data: ( data, rptnew, recid ),
        dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result) {
            alert("Data Saved Successfully");
            afterpostfunctions();
        }
        else
            alert(result);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error Occured, Try Again");
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult UpdateDB_IR(DATABASE_RECORDS dbData, string rptNew, string recId)
```

The problem:
dbData contains the columns and values from the variable data.
rptNew does not contain the value from rptnew.
recId does not contain the value from recid.

If I stringify the data like:

```
JSON.stringify({ dbData: data, rptNew: rptnew, recId: recid });
```

dbData does not contain the values from data.
rptNew contains the value from rptnew.
recId contains the value from recid.

I’m at a loss on how to send all values over correctly to the controller. Any suggestions?

database class:

```
namespace REPORTSYS.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class DATABASE_RECORDS
{
    public int CBAD_ID { get; set; }
    public int TRAYS { get; set; }
    public int M26850 { get; set; }
    public int M26860 { get; set; }
    public int X26930 { get; set; }
    public int T26920 { get; set; }
    public int C2501 { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function postdata(data, section, recid, rptnew) {
$.ajax
    ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'UpdateDB_IR’,
        async: false,
        data: { dbData : data, rptNew : rptnew, recId : recid },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
        if (result) {
            alert("Data Saved Successfully");
            afterpostfunctions();
        }
        else
            alert(result);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error Occured, Try Again");
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Send data with key to the controller. As modified in above function.

Comment: I tried your solution, dbData contains a null value, rptNew and recId contain values.

Comment: Can you share the class structure of `DATABASE_RECORDS` ?

Comment: namespace REPORTSYS.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class DATABASE_RECORDS
    {
        public int CBAD_ID { get; set; }
        public int TRAYS { get; set; }
        public int M26850 { get; set; }
        public int M26860 { get; set; }
        public int X26930 { get; set; }
        public int T26920 { get; set; }
        public int C2501 { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: my apologies, I'm not sure how to format that block of code. edit: I posted the database class formatted in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on data

data: { dbData: data, rptNew: rptnew, recId: recid }

Don't use stringify.

Comment: Using this solution resulted in dbData containing a null value. rptNew and recId did have values.

Comment: Try using all the data you need in model 

eg.

public class DB_IR_UpdateRequest
{
public DATABASE_RECORDS dbData {get;set;}
public string rptNew{get;set;}
public string recId{get;set;}
}
and change 
public ActionResult UpdateDB_IR(DB_IR_UpdateRequest request)